Using Velocity/Breath Control with a Vangoa EWI-100 and SurgeXT
I've been having trouble using this electronic wind instrument's breath control on Surge XT. I verified that it sends signals to my PC using the aseqdump command on Linux. The output is below.
aseqdump -p 28:0
Waiting for data. Press Ctrl+C to end.
Source  Event                  Ch  Data
 28:0   Note on                 0, note 74, velocity 120
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 15
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 22
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 27
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 31
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 35
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 38
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 35
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 38
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 42
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 38
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 42
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 44
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 42
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 44
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 42
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 44
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 42
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 44
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 42
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 38
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 35
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 31
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 27
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 22
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 15
 28:0   Control change          0, controller 7, value 0
 28:0   Note off                0, note 74, velocity 0


The number after "value" is what changes as I blow air through the instrument faster or slower. I've tried all the modulation sources that I can find, but none of them worked. (Poly AT, Channel AT, Pitch Bend, Modwheel, Breath, Expression, Sustain, Timbre) In the screenshot below shows how I tested to see if "Breath" would be able to modulate the pitch. I did this for the other modulation sources as well.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? My first guess is that my SurgeXT settings are incorrect, and my second guess is that the MIDI device is reporting the breath to the PC incorrectly. In any case, I'd really appreciate the help if anyone has an idea at an answer. Thanks for reading!

What are the choices you have in surge xt? If possible you should choose cc7 on channel 0. If that is not available you can shift it using another software like qmidiroute.

That was the issue! Thank you, Tom for your help. I assigned one of the macros to cc7, and I am able to modulate anything with that.
